# Count values in column and put in new column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to count how many times a value is in the column *furniture*, however this column may sometimes be in a different place. So I'd have to refer to the name instead of column number. Eventually create a new column where it is stated how many times that furniture appears. Below you find a simple example.

| owner | furniture |
| --- | --- |
| owen | chair |
| mila | table |
| will |  |
| jack | chair |
| zoe | lamp |
| mike | lamp |
| maya | chair |

Wanted outcome

| owner | furniture | groupsize |
| --- | --- | --- |
| owen | chair | 3 |
| mila | table | 1 |
| will |  |  |
| jack | chair | 3 |
| zoe | lamp | 2 |
| mike | lamp | 2 |
| maya | chair | 1 |

'Chair' appears 3 times in the column *furniture*

I'm aware of the `countif` formula, but I need vba. I tried several things, but neither came close. Any suggestions?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`? Or, you can write a formula with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

### Unique Count Using a Dictionary

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountFurniture()
    
    Const sColName As String = "furniture"
    Const dColName As String = "groupsize"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With rg
        
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers or nothing
        
        Dim sCol As Variant: sCol = Application.Match(sColName, .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsError(sCol) Then Exit Sub ' source column not found
        sData = .Columns(sCol).Value
        
        Dim dCol As Variant: dCol = Application.Match(dColName, .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsError(dCol) Then dCol = .Columns.Count + 1
        Set drg = .Columns(dCol)
    
    End With
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
                
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 2 To rCount
        Key = sData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                dict(Key) = dict(Key) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    dData(1, 1) = dColName
    
    For r = 2 To rCount
        dData(r, 1) = dict(sData(r, 1))
    Next r
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
End Sub
```